# FFMPEG: how to determine which filters are supported by specific hardware acceleration contexts?

Tags: ffmpeg, hardware-acceleration

I'm having trouble figuring out precisely which filter graph operations are supported by each of the available hardware acceleration methods. I know, for example, that almost all of these methods perform simple operations like scaling, but what about more complicated ffmpeg filters like the new `v360` filter or the `mestimate` filter?

There's this page (https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HWAccelIntro) that everyone finds when researching hardware accel with ffmpeg but it mostly touched on encoding and decoding and not filtering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Filters which can operate upon frames on the GPU will have names that identify them as such e.g. `scale_vaapi` `overlay_qsv` or `yadif_cuda`. Run `ffmpeg -filters | grep vaapi` to identify all VAAPI supported filters in your build.